# What is the stanceof Islam on an unmarried or divorced woman engaging in cybersex?

Tags: fiqh, adultery

What is the stance of Islam on explicit sexual roleplay on the Internet (cybersex) with someone they are not married to?

Comment: Question edited to remove unnecessary details. We cannot answer questions relating to modern political entities and their legal systems. Also, the ruling is the same for men and women, so I removed that specification from the question as well.

Comment: Sharia is more likely a reference to Islam cybersex is a modern issue so fiqh is the better choice for a tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to Islam, it is considered as haram practice to have such relations as you said

> explicit sexual roleplay on the Internet (cybersex) with someone they
>   are not married to.

Since this kind of relation can be led to haram (forbidden) acts (or thoughts) and actually Satan will be the third person between you and the person who you are chatting to. Reading the following two sites would be constructive and helpful for you as two related issues.

- [http://www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1427) &  [this](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa355)

Comment: Your welcome @EidolonSpectre. Many people interested in doing many  Sins, but I reckon solely a limited group of them are great and successful in front of the sins. God willing, you can be counted as one of those Mo'mens who can overcome sins. Then Allah will give you much more than ... Good luck.